# How to use mopub banner in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, banner, mopub

I was wondering if anyone knew how to use mopub in swiftui. I have been trying and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to use a banner ad with Mopub in swiftui. Thanks.

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MoPub does not provide SwiftUI specific UI right now (they have stated that they have [no plans](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/issues/375) supporting it), you need to use UIViewRepresentable classes for representing UIKit views in SwiftUI.

If you want to give it a try yourself, start from [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-wrap-a-custom-uiview-for-swiftui).

Also there are great examples out there that you can check for MoPub:

For example [this](https://github.com/adampax/MoPubSwiftUIDemo) or [this](https://adampaxton.com/how-to-use-mopub-banner-ads-in-swiftui/).